# I am not able to figure out what wrong did I commit in making this MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 INT, PRIMARY KEY (s1));
DELIMITER ;
CREATE PROCEDURE handlerdemo ()
BEGIN
DECLARE x INTEGER;
SET @x = 1; 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1); 
SET @x = 2; 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1); 
SET @x = 3; 
END;
```

WHEN I run this query I get 1064 error at line 4.
Any hint on how to deal with it is highly appreciated.

Comment: You must use a delimiter other than `;` when declaring a procedure (or function, or trigger...) e.g. `DELIMITER $$` and then finish with `END $$`

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to set Delimiter to anything **except** `;`
- Optionally, put a check if the same name stored procedure already exists.
- At the end, redefine the Delimiter back to `;`
- Unless, you are going to use variable `x` outside this stored procedure; you really dont need to use `@`; it makes the variable available everywhere in that particular session).

Try (more explanation in the comments):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 INT, PRIMARY KEY (s1)); -- create the table

DELIMITER $$ -- redefine the delimiter to $$ (for eg)

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `handlerdemo` $$ -- drop previous if exists

CREATE PROCEDURE handlerdemo ()
  BEGIN

    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0; -- datatype is INT 
    -- also a good practice to set default value

    SET x = 1; -- no need to use in Session context
    INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (x); -- use variable name here instead of literal value

    SET x = 2; 
    INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (x); 

  END $$ -- remember that delimiter is $$ right now

-- redefine the Delimiter back to ;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to remove ; (semicolon) after DELIMITER it will work fine

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 INT, PRIMARY KEY (s1));
DELIMITER -- just remove this ; from your query it will work fine
CREATE PROCEDURE handlerdemo ()
BEGIN
DECLARE x INTEGER;
SET @x = 1; 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1); 
SET @x = 2; 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1); 
SET @x = 3; 
END;
```