# My Mysql procedure encounter syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS oneTimeExcution;

CREATE PROCEDURE `oneTimeExcution`()

begin


   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;


   DECLARE totalCount int(10) default 0;

   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;


   DECLARE nowUnixTime int(10) unsigned default 0;

   DECLARE id varchar(100) default null;

   DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT deviceId FROM tb_sensor;



   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


   select (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-31622400) into nowUnixTime;

   select count(*) from tb_sensor into totalCount;


   OPEN cur;

             FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO id;

   close cur;

   read_loop: loop

   IF done then

   LEAVE read_loop;

   END IF;

   END LOOP;

end;
```

I currently encounter syntax errors in `end if` and `end loop`s. I do not know why. pleas.. Please let me know what the problem is.
My current version of MySQL is 5.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am not able to figure out what wrong did I commit in making this MYSQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886160/i-am-not-able-to-figure-out-what-wrong-did-i-commit-in-making-this-mysql-query)

Comment: You must use delimiter other than ';' as procedure is complete one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `oneTimeExcution`()

begin


   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;


   DECLARE totalCount int(10) default 0;

   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;


   DECLARE nowUnixTime int(10) unsigned default 0;

   DECLARE id varchar(100) default null;

   DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT deviceId FROM tb_sensor;



   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


   select (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-31622400) into nowUnixTime;

   select count(*) from tb_sensor into totalCount;


   OPEN cur;

   read_loop: loop
             FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO id;

   IF done then

   LEAVE read_loop;

   END IF;

select 'success'; # condition comes here

   END LOOP;
   close cur;
end;
```